# Change the port of a Spring boot application without changing the code

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot

I have two applications that I need to run simultaneously, and both are trying to run on port `8080`. I'd like to change one of them to port `9000`. The application I'm trying to change has spring security, so it runs on port `8443` when using `https` and port `8080` when using `http`. I have to move it from port `8080` without changing any `.java` files. Also, I need to run the other application on port `8080` as well, so changing the default tomcat port wouldn't be a good idea.

I tried adding to `application.properties` the lines `server.port=9000`, `spring.main.server.port=9000`, then running `mvn install`, and then `java -jar target/app.jar`.

I also tried running `java -jar target/app.jar` with different flags: `-Dserver.port=9000` and `--server.port=9000`.

Regardless, I get `- Tomcat started on port(s): 8443 (https) 8080 (http)`.

So, my questions are:

- How do I get it to run on a port different from `8080`?
- And, what could be causing the configuration files to not change the port?

Comment: Spring Boot will only start on a single port by default so your application must contain some code that's configuring Tomcat's connectors. I suspect that code is preventing server.port from having any effect, possibly because the port numbers have been hard-coded. Can you share the code that's configuring Tomcat's connectors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run the following command:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments='-Dserver.port=8088'
```

Add the following `plugin` to your `pom.xml` file

```
<build>
    . . . 
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Why not just use `-Dserver.port=8088`?

Comment: Starting from Spring Boot 2, you should use `spring-boot.run.jvmArguments`.